# Dictionary and list lookup based on key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lookup

```
input_list = [
    'thissong-fav-user:ABC-chan-44-John', 
    'thissong-fav-user:type1-jsjd01-45-kelly-md', 
    'thissong-fav-user:type2-rock-45-mkr5', 
    'thissong-fav-user:type737-chan-45-fft-md', 
    'thissong-fav-user:type37-chan-45-kelly-md']
]


mainlookup = {'ABC': {'Price': '30', 'Song': 'Reggaeton', 'Type': 'Hard'},
 'JSJD': {'Price': '10', 'Song': 'Rock', 'Type': 'Hard'},
 'fft': {'Price': '1', 'Song': 'Rock', 'Type': 'Soft'},
 'mkr': {'Price': '99', 'Song': 'Jazz', 'Type': 'Hard'}}


OUTPUT_DICT = {
 'thissong-fav-user:ABC-chan-44-John': {'Price': '30',
                                        'Song': 'Reggaeton',
                                        'Type': 'Hard'},
 'thissong-fav-user:type1-jsjd01-45-kelly-md': {'Price': '10',
                                                'Song': 'Rock',
                                                'Type': 'Hard'},
 'thissong-fav-user:type2-rock-45-mkr5': {'Price': '99',
                                          'Song': 'Jazz',
                                          'Type': 'Hard'},
 'thissong-fav-user:type737-chan-45-fft-md': {'Price': '1',
                                              'Song': 'Rock',
                                              'Type': 'Soft'}}
```

i tried

```
OUTPUT_DICT = {i: mainlookup.values() 
                  for i in input_list 
                  if mainlookup.keys() in input_list}
```

but getting empty dictionary

Comment: To see if a key is in a dict, "if key in my_dict" and to get the value, you're still going to need the key, my_dict[key] And to find the terms to search for, you're going to have to parse those text strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
OUTPUT_DICT = dict()
for i in mainlookup:
    for j in input_list:
        if i.lower() in j.lower():
            OUTPUT_DICT[j] = mainlookup[i]
```

Comment: I'd worry that there's no dict lookup. O(n^2) and risks false positives (but not on this data set)

Comment: That is true. i have relatively small dataset so this will work but you for larger dataset this will give lot of false positives.